# selenium vba runtime-error 438

Tags: vba, selenium

I am learning [Selenium VBA](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/). I want to use `HideCommandPromptwindow` in Selenium VBA.

The code bellow returns `runtime-error 438` error.

> **HideCommandPromptWindow** example:

[image]

Attached print-screen source: https://github.com/danwagnerco/selenium-vba/issues/68.

**My code:**

```
Sub abc()
Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
driver.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
driver.Start "chrome", "https://www.google.com"
driver.Quit
driver.Close
End Sub
```

**Error:**

For `driver.HideCommandPromptWindow = True`I'm prompted with `runtime error 438 object doesn't support this property or method`.

How can I use it? Have a nice day!

Comment: I don't know the selenium API, but apparently `SeleniumWrapper` doesn't have a `HideCommandPromptWindow` method, or the VBA run-time would have found it. Re-type the dot; is there a `HideCommandPromptWindow` member in the list? If not, you need to use something that's there. If yes, then the API isn't raising standard errors, or is twisting their meaning and in that case I'd refer to the API's documentation.. what does it say about `HideCommandPromptWindow`?

Answer (score 1):

The .HideCommandPromptWindow property was available from version 1.0.18

You are getting that error because you are using an old version of the wrapper. My guess is that you are using version 1.0.17.

Please download the latest version from the below link and try again. I tried with version 1.0.17 and I got the error but when I installed the version 1.0.18, it worked just fine as shown in the screenshot below.

[Selenium Wrapper Setup File](https://bintray.com/florentbr/generic/selenium-vba/view/files#files/)

Solution copied from origin:

[selenium vba runtime-error 438](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?847837-selenium-vba-runtime-error-438&p=5171863#post5171863)

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and avoid link only answers.